# Representing graphs as induced subgraphs of $\text{Hom}(H,K)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $H, K$ be simple, undirected graphs, and let $\text{Hom}(H,K)$ the collection of graph homomorphisms $f: H\to K$. (Note that $\text{Hom}(H,K)$ might be empty.) For $f,g\in \text{Hom}(H,K)$ we say that they form an edge if $\{f(v),g(v)\}\in E(K)$ for all $v\in V(H)$ (which implies $f\neq g$ if $V(H) \neq \emptyset$). With this construction, we make $\text{Hom}(H,K)$ into a simple, undirected graph.

Given any simple, undirected graph $G$, are there simple, undirected graphs $H, K$ such that $|V(H)|>1$ and $G$ is isomorphic to an [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) of $\text{Hom}(H,K)$?

Comment: Let H be a Cartesian product of G and K. I would think G would be a subgraph of the homomorphism graph. Gerhard "Turn Each Map Into Vertex" Paseman, 2019.12.09.

Comment: I assume the requirement $|V(H)|>1$ is to rule out choosing $H=K_1$ and $K=G$. But instead one could let $H=K_2$ and $K$ be the join $G+G$ of two disjoint copies of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! If one of you can post their comment as an answer, we can close this thread